# C++ delete pointer after scanf() reading results in process termination

Tags: c++

Could you explain to me why on earth this code terminates the process?

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
    int *wsk = new int[2];

    scanf("%d %d", wsk[0], wsk[1]); // relevant line

    delete [] wsk;
    wsk = new int[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas this one does not:

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
    int *wsk = new int[2];

    scanf("%d %d", &wsk[0], &wsk[1]); // relevant line, mark the two '&'

    delete [] wsk;
    wsk = new int[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` is hard to use and error-prone (as you've discovered) so do not use it. Your question is basically "why does my buggy program crash but my correct one doesn't?" and you shouldn't need an answer to that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, `scanf` is a legitimate function to use in C/C++. I use it all the time, I and I expect my programs to work.

Comment: "why on earth" Well, it appears to be the absence of these things: `&`. It's shouldn't too surprising that changing code changes behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` takes pointers.

It has to know the *address* of where to put the read in value.

`wsk[0]` and `wsk[1]` are some random (actually, undefined) `int`s. They are used as addresses, but they were invalid addresses. Seg fault.

`&wsk[0]` and `&wsk[1]`, or more concisely, `wsk` and `wsk+1`, are a valid addresses, where `scanf` can write an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not passing in pointers to the scanf function in the first case.  You are passing in the *value* of wsk[0] and wsk[1] and treating those values as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

a) Both codes will terminate at least when they are finished.
b) You´re not deleting all reservations before the program ends.
c) You program is a mix of C and C++.
  ...
d) scanf take addresses to variables. &